# radeon 7640 laptop 16.04 work-arounds

Tags: unity, drivers, fglrx

I have Radeon 7640 video in my laptop. I don't like opensource radeon driver. It's slow as hell (and makes my laptop hot as hellfire too).

But, it's a good machine with 4 cores, I love it.

I heard fglrx isn't compatible with new X server. Can I drop X server, install wayland and install fglrx?

I have another option: stay with radeon driver but switch from unity to lxde/metacity or gnomeFallback/metacity. I guess it will be faster, because metacity uses 2d not slow 3d. Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys, I had software rendering enabled, (because of nomodeset in /etc/default/grub)

radeon opensource works ok for me.